# SingleEmailMessage() not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

**HTML TEMPLATE**

//LOOK THE TEMPLATE (), inside that there is a 'Send' button calling handleSend()
lightning:card

```
<template if:true={bShowMail}>
  <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
     <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <!-- modal header start -->
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
          
           <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Send Quotation to customer</h2>
        </header>
        <!-- modal body start -->
        
        <lightning-card>
        <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">

           <lightning-input label="Enquirer" name="display" type="textarea" value={disName} ></lightning-input>
           <lightning-input label="Agreement cost" name="pricCost" type="Double" value={finalCost} ></lightning-input>
          <lightning-input label="Recipient mailID" name="recp" type="email" ></lightning-input>
         
 
   <lightning-button label="Send" onclick={handleSend}></lightning-button>
   <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
  
  
         </p>
         </lightning-card>
        <!-- modal footer start-->
      
     </div>
  </section>
```

Close
             
             Quotation

```
        <lightning-input label="Date" name="datefld" type="date" value={fDate} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Quotation Name" name="enquiry" type="textarea" value={enq} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>

        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
           <lightning-input-field field-name="Project__c" onchange={projectChange}>
           </lightning-input-field>
           </lightning-record-edit-form>
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Unit__c"  onchange={unitChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

```
 <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>


       </p>
       </lightning-card>
      <!-- modal footer start-->
    
   </div>
</section>
```

### Estimation

```
<div if:true={accList}>
    <lightning-datatable data={accList} columns={columns} key-field="Id" onclick={handleclick} >
    </lightning-datatable>
  </div>
<div if:true={error}>
    {error}
</div>
</lightning:card>
```

**js**

```
import { LightningElement , wire, track} from 'lwc';
import priceMail from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.priceMail';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.getAccountList';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
      @track enqMail;
    @track engAgree;
    @track enqEmail;
       @track bShowMail = false;
       @track Name;
    @track columns = [
        {  
            label: "Name",  
            fieldName: "recordLink",
            type: "url",  
            typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" },  target:"_self" }  
           },
            ];
 
   
    @track error;
    @track accList ;
  
    @wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            var tempOppList = [];  
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                
             let tempRecord = Object.assign({}, data[i]); //cloning object  
             tempRecord.Name = tempRecord.Name;
             tempRecord.recordLink = "/" + tempRecord.Id;  
            
             tempOppList.push(tempRecord);  
            }  
            console.log('hHIIII' + data)
            this.accList = tempOppList;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
```

handleSend(event) {
alert(event.target.label);
var inp=this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input");

```
    inp.forEach(function(element){
        if(element.name=="display")
            this.enqMail=element.value;

        else if(element.name=="pricCost")
            this.enqAgree=element.value;

        else if(element.name=="recp")
            this.enqEmail=element.value;
    },this);
    this.bShowMail = false;
    alert('TESTING' + this.enqEmail + this.enqAgree + this.enqMail);
    priceMail({ name: this.enqMail, email:this.enqEmail, cost:this.enqAgree })
    .then(result => {
        alert('SHOW' +result);
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Mail Sent succesfully',
            variant: 'success',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        console.log("Opps updated!" + result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
    });
}

    }
```

//HERE I AM CALLING THE sentMail() in the apex controller class 'PriceFetch', But it is not working

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public with sharing class PriceFetch {
    public static List<Price__c> getAccountList() {
        System.debug('HII');
        return [SELECT Id,  Name
            FROM Price__c ];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String priceMail(String name, String email, Double cost) {
        // Create an email message object
        String sMessage='';
        String subject = 'Price List';
        String body = 'Dear ' + name + '/n' + 'ggg' + cost;
        try{
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        // Pass this email message to the built-in sendEmail method 
        // of the Messaging class
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(
                                 new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        sMessage='Success';
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            sMessage=ex.getLineNumber()+'\n'+ex.getCause()+'\n'+ex.getMessage()+'\n'+ex.getStackTraceString();
        }
        return sMessage;
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone, please help me

Comment: Is your sMessage variable in the Apex class returning an error message or is it returning "Success"? Could you share the message if it is erroring out?

Comment: I'm getting the 'success' message, but the message is not delivered

Comment: Can you check the email logs to see if the email was sent, and if there are any reasons the email failed to send if so? Can find it under Setup --> Email Log Files

Comment: Email log is empty!!

Comment: Out of interest, what are your deliverability settings (Setup --> Deliverability), it should be "All email"

Comment: yes, it is 
All Email''